# Form not responding correctly to php function

Tags: php, forms, if-statement, connection

I'm trying to get my form working correctly but if i post my form data it just refreshes the website. The Log In form should be hidden when I'm logged in but that is also not happening.

UPDATE:
still not working, i puts the value out in the URL but i don't think it responds to the function yet.

If anyone has teamviewer and would like to help me trough chat/spectate it would be a lot easier to solve this. 
REMOTE ID: 532 027 730 
PASS: vsu868

I would love to do something back for the ones that could help me out, im a graphic designer so i could help back with any graphic needs.

Thanks.

This is code right now:

```
if($_POST['submit']){
    $gbn = sha1($_POST['gbn']);
    $ww = sha1($_POST['ww']);
    if(!$gbn || !$ww){
        // Check if no data is sent. if true, message the error.
        echo "<span style='color:#F04A60;'>Geen gegevens ingevuld, probeer opnieuw.</span>";
        /*echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.location.href='../products.php';</script>";*/
    }else{
        // Check if username exists in database.
        $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE gbn = '".$gbn."'");
        $num = mysql_num_rows($res);

        if($num == 0){
            // Message Error
            echo "<span style='color:#F04A60;'>Gebruikersnaam onjuist, probeer opnieuw.</span>";
            /*echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.location.href='../products.php';</script>";*/
        }else{

            // We have a match!
            // Check if there is match between the username and password in the Database.
            $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE `username` = '".$gbn."' AND `password` = '".$ww."'");
            $num = mysql_num_rows($res);

            if($num == 0){
                // Message Error
                echo "<span style='color:#F04A60;'>Wachtwoord onjuist, probeer opnieuw.</span>";
            /*  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.location.href='../products.php';</script>";*/
            }else{
                //if there was continue checking
                //split all fields fom the correct row into an associative array
                $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
                $_SESSION['uid'] = $row['id'];
                //show message
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.location.href='../products.php?u=" . $gbn . "';</script>";
                //if they have log them in
                //set the login session storing there id - we use this to see if they are logged in 
            }
        }
    }
}

if(isset($_SESSION['uid'])){
    echo "Welcome $gbn, klik <a href='shoppingcart.php'>hier</a> om naar uw winkelwagen te gaan";
    }
    else{
    ?>
    <!-- LOG IN DIV--> 
        <div id="login">
            <form name="form2" methode="POST" action="">
                <h2>Log in</h2>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" required="" id="gbn" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required="" id="ww" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input class="button" type="submit" value="log In" />
                    <a href="passwordhelp.php">Lost your password?</a>
                    <a href="register.php">Register</a>
                </div>
            </form><!-- form -->
        </div>
     <?php
        } 
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling a $_POST with name "submit", but your button have no name

Try this

```
<input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="log In" />
```